# Expanding tree node in QTP

Tags: vbscript, treeview, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to expand a tree node in an application using HP UFT.
I tried using `Swfwindow("Windowname").SwfTreeView("Treename").Expand "nodename"`

I tried sending keyboard buttons via script : rightarrow, leftarrow, +, -, *

But it is of no use. The application does not allow to expand the tree.

The tree structure is like : `(+)treeName`

So working around, I manually expanded and collapsed the tree, then tried running the script, it seem to worked.
So this suggests the tree does not expand using the script, but if I manually expand and close and then try the script, it works fine.

Could you suggest if I can handle this kind of application build in QTP?

Comment: Have you used `Swfwindow("Windowname").SwfTreeView("Treename").Activate "Parent;Child1"`?

Comment: Yes..I have tried this, but it doesn't work too.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Swfwindow("Windowname").SwfTreeView("Treename").Activate "Parent;Child1"
followed by Swfwindow("Windowname").SwfTreeView("Treename").Type micDwn